# inline css mvc issue

Tags: css, model-view-controller

I am trying to put inline css into an mvc page which inherits from a master page. I want to do this because this css is page specific and I feel it shouldn't go into a site wide file. What is the best way of doing this. My failed attempt is below. Nothing on the site will recognize testTwo styling. Thank you

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
        .test
        {
        }
        .testTwo *
        {
            float: left;
            padding: 5px;
            border: 2px solid gray;
            margin: 3px;
        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

missing the opening `<style>` tag? *bad copy-paste, not the issue*

---

Where is this `ContentPlaceHolder` at in your `MasterPage`?

Often times the `TitleContent` ContentPlaceHolder is inside the `<head>` tag within the `<title>` element like so:

```
<title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
```

Is this the case? If so, those styles will not be interpreted since browsers won't recognize the styles within `<title><style>..</style></title>`

---

I would suggest updating your MasterPage like this:

```
<head>
    <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
    <link.... />
    <link.... />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="StylesheetContent" runat="server" />
    <script.... />
    <script.... />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ScriptContent" runat="server" />
</head>
```

Comment: bad copy and paste. Thank you for noticing

Answer (score 0):

Where is your opening

```
<style type="text/css">
```

?